# How to reference ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to convert the string:

```
"{john:123456}"
```

to:

```
"<script src='https://gist.github.com/john/123456.js'>"
```

I wrote a method that works, but it is very stupid. It is like this:

```
def convert
    args = []

    self.scan(/{([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+):(\d+)}/) {|x| args << x}  

    args.each do |pair|
       name = pair[0]
       id = pair[1]
       self.gsub!("{" + name + ":" + id + "}", "<script src='https://gist.github.com/#{name}/#{id}.js'></script>")
    end 

    self
end
```

Is there a way to do this just like the `cool_method` below?

```
"{john:123}".cool_method(/{([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+):(\d+)}/, "<script src='https://gist.github.com/$1/$2.js'></script>")
```

Comment: If this is coming in as JSON from somewhere, I'd just use JSON. And while the regex solution is "nice", I'd still consider just splitting and chopping/indexing the resulting values.

Comment: +1 @DaveNewton. The incoming data string is JSON, so the first step is to turn it back to its object form, then massage it. Parsing JSON with Regex can blow up badly. Massaging values in a hash or array is a lot less likely to go boom.

Comment: Will there always be only one name/value, or can multiple entries be received? And, is the string `"{john:123456}"` or is it really `'{"john":123456}'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That cool method is gsub.    You were so close!   Just change the $1 and $2 to \\1 and \\2

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub

```
"{john:123}".gsub(/{([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+):(\d+)}/, 
  "<script src='https://gist.github.com/\\1/\\2.js'></script>")
```

Comment: @Shawn: thank you for your kind, i think i should to learn more ruby-basic, best regards to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
def convert
    /{(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+):(?<id>\d+)}/ =~ self
    "<script src='https://gist.github.com/#{name}/#{id}.js'></script>"
end
```

Please see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Capturing for more details.

Comment: Why open the String class for such a specialized method?

Comment: I wouldnt either but using string interpolation is really the way to go here.

Comment: @Jueecy.new OP's `convert` looks like a member function of String class. Anyway, I think Shawn's answer is better.

Comment: @ZifeiTong, if you generalize it enough, yes. But as it current stands it's way too specialized ( the string is hardcoded in the method ) to even be a method.

Comment: thank you for your code, your method is clean. best regards to you.

Comment: @Jueecy.new. yes, you are right, it's bad to open string class, but i have just write a test method in irb, thank you for your point.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "{john:123456}".scan(/\w+|\d+/).each_with_object("<script src='https://gist.github.com") do |i,ob|
  ob<< "/" + i
end.concat(".js'>")
p s #=> "<script src='https://gist.github.com/john/123456.js'>"
```

Comment: thank you for your code, i have know that the scan and each_with_object methods can working together. best regards to you.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a JSON string, so, as @DaveNewton said, treat it as one:

```
require 'json'
json = '{"john":123456}' 
name, value = JSON[json].flatten
"<script src='https://gist.github.com/#{ name }/#{ value }.js'></script>"
=> "<script src='https://gist.github.com/john/123456.js'></script>"
```

Why not treat it as a string and use a regular expression on it? Because JSON isn't a simple format for parsing via regular expressions, which can cause errors as the values change or the data string gets more complex.